# extract values in array and create variable PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have this code:

```
$result = print_r($reponse, true); 

echo $result;
```

Which gives me this output:

```
Array ( [333212] => Array ( [view] => 323 [sold] => 3 [buy] => 43 [number] => 333212 ) )
```

I need to find a way to have something like:

```
echo $variable['view']; (323)

echo $variable['buy']; (3)

echo $variable['sold']; (43)
```

I checked and tried a lot of things like extract(); serialize(); dump_var. I tried explode("")  I searched a little everywhere but didn't find an answer.

Thanks a lot for the help! much appreciated!

Comment: guess you mean `echo $response['sold']` ...?

Comment: I try this but i dont know why the output gave me nothing. been hours iam on this i feel stupid :) Thanks a lot everyone for your fast reply you are awesome !

Comment: I know why its because it put [] and there is no "," after each value, i used str_replace to repair the problem with [] now all i need is just  to add "," after each value but i have no idea how to proceed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using multi array

```
 <?php
   $response = Array ( "333212" => Array ( "view" => 323, "sold" => 3, "buy" => 43, "number" => 333212 ) ) ;
   $variable = $response["333212"];
   echo $variable['view']."\n";
   echo $variable['buy']."\n";
   echo $variable['sold'];
?>
```

Demo : https://eval.in/765754

Comment: Very nice but please how do i guess the response will be "333212" because it could be anything (in my script) THanks a lot !!!

Comment: Ho no sorry i know i will create a variable ok ok sorry its a perfect answer thanks a billion time friend !

Comment: Your code work but when i adjust them with my code i got a blank page very bizarre

Comment: maybe its because you have "" have i have [] ? i really dont know

Comment: Yeah i think its exactly that ! i try str_replace but no result i will try harder :)

Comment: Praticly got it, no i just need to add the "," after each value , have an idea how because i really dont :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$reponse = array(); //Replace with your array

echo $reponse['view'];
//Returns: 323
```

Answer (score 0):

You can output array values with the specific index this way:

```
echo $reponse['333212']['view'];
```

Like in your example, if you want to use `$variable` you can assign the array `$reponse` to `$variable`:

`$variable['333212'] = $reponse;`

Then your code would work:

```
echo $variable['view']; // (323)
echo $variable['buy']; // (3)
echo $variable['sold']; // (43)
```

Also consider renaming `reponse` to `response` (typo?).

Comment: Or he meant 'réponse' in french ;)

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that. :)